# Speed up Response Time - Isotope with 200+ products on one html page

Tags: javascript, html, lazy-loading, jquery-isotope, infinite-scroll

I have a webpage with more than 8000 lines of html to render.
I'm using `jquery-isotope` in combination with `imgLazyload` for all the product images.

That means all "filterable" content is on one page. Using this

```
(function() {
    var $container = $("#isotopeContainer");

    $container.imagesLoaded(function() {
        $container.isotope({
            itemSelector: ".span3",
            layoutMode: "fitRows",
            onLayout: function() {
                $container.trigger("scroll");
            },
            getSortData: {
                price: function($elm) {
                    return $elm.data("price");
                },
                name: function($elm) {
                    return $elm.find(".isotope--title").text();
                },
                popularity: function($elm) {
                    return $elm.data("popularity");
                }
            }
        });

        // jQuery UI slider
        var prepareCurrency = function(value) {
            return WebMarketVars.currencyBefore ? WebMarketVars.currencySymbol + value : value + WebMarketVars.currencySymbol;
        };
        var $slider = $(".jqueryui-slider-container > div");
        $slider.slider({
            range: true,
            min: WebMarketVars.priceRange[0],
            max: WebMarketVars.priceRange[1],
            values: WebMarketVars.priceRange,
            step: WebMarketVars.priceStep,
            slide: function(ev, ui) {
                $(this).parent().siblings(".min-val").val(prepareCurrency(ui.values[0]));
                $(this).parent().siblings(".max-val").val(prepareCurrency(ui.values[1]));
            },
            change: function() {
                updateIsotopeFiltering();
            },
            create: function() {
                var $sliderParent = $(this).parents(".accordion-body");
                $sliderParent.find(".min-val").val(prepareCurrency($(this).slider("values", 0)));
                $sliderParent.find(".max-val").val(prepareCurrency($(this).slider("values", 1)));
            }
        });
        //  ========== 
        //  = Filters for sidebar = 
        //  ========== 
        var $selectableElms = $(".sidebar-filters .selectable");
        $selectableElms.click(function(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            $(this).toggleClass("selected");
            updateIsotopeFiltering();
        });
        $(".sidebar-filters .accordion-toggle").click(function() {
            setTimeout(updateIsotopeFiltering, 350);
        });
        $("#removeFilters").click(function(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            $selectableElms.removeClass("selected");
            updateIsotopeFiltering();
        });
        var updateIsotopeFiltering = function() {
            var selectedElms = $(".sidebar-filters .in").find(".selectable.selected[data-target]").not(".detailed"), detailedElms = $(".sidebar-filters .in").find(".detailed.selected[data-target]"), filterString, filter, types = [];
            if (selectedElms.length > 0 || detailedElms.length > 0) {
                $("#removeFilters").fadeIn();
            } else {
                $("#removeFilters").fadeOut();
            }
            if (selectedElms.length < 1) {
                filterString = ".isotope-container .span3";
            } else {
                var filterArr = [];
                selectedElms.each(function() {
                    var data = $(this).data("target");
                    if ("undefined" !== typeof data) {
                        filterArr.push($(this).data("target"));
                    }
                });
                filterString = filterArr.join(",");
            }
            // basic filtering
            filter = $(filterString);
            // slider price filtering, after we have the right categories already
            if ($slider.parents(".accordion-body").hasClass("in")) {
                filter = filter.filter(function() {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    return $this.data("price") >= $slider.slider("values", 0) && $this.data("price") <= $slider.slider("values", 1);
                });
            }
            // more precise filters for the size, color, brand ...
            detailedElms.each(function() {
                types.push($(this).data("type"));
            });
            types = _.uniq(types);
            if (detailedElms.length > 0) {
                _.each(types, function(type) {
                    var allowedValues = [];
                    detailedElms.filter('[data-type="' + type + '"]').each(function() {
                        allowedValues.push($(this).data("target"));
                    });
                    filter = filter.filter(function() {
                        var $this = $(this);
                        return _.some($this.data(type).split("|"), function(val) {
                            return _.contains(allowedValues, val);
                        });
                    });
                });
            }
            $container.isotope({
                filter: filter
            });
        };
        updateIsotopeFiltering();
        //  ========== 
        //  = Sorting = 
        //  ========== 
        $("#isotopeSorting").change(function() {
            var parameters = jQuery.parseJSON($(this).val());
            parameters.sortAscending = "true" === parameters.sortAscending ? true : false;
            $container.isotope(parameters);
        });
        $("#isotopeSorting").trigger("change");
    });
})();

$("img.lazy").lazyload({
    event: "scroll",
    effect : "fadeIn",
    threshold : 100,
    failure_limit: Math.max($("img.lazy").length - 1, 0)
});`
```

Minify HTML, CSS and JS is activated and all render-blocking content was moved to the end.
I do not want paging as then isotop filtering would not working anymore. Is there any soultion?

Comment: Have your profiled your code using developer tools, what takes the most time? You need to identify your bottleneck.

Comment: Its 11 seconds on the first request. The "Html" page. the rest after that is around 1 sec at most. See img: [link](http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=6c8998d)

Comment: In Lazy-Load-XT plugin it has been fixed by adding "layoutComplete" event: https://github.com/ressio/lazy-load-xt/issues/11 So, I guess 'event: "scroll layoutComplete"' should work in your case.

Comment: I'am actually not using Lazy-Load-XT // or is it migrate compatible ?